# Initialize an Java Object in Spring xml

Tags: spring, object, initialization, javabeans, code-injection

How to Initialize an Java Object in Spring xml
if you have a class and you want to create an object from this class, but without Initialization, so the Initialization will be done in XML. so how

in xml .    logger = Logger.getRootLogger();

import org.apache.log4j.*;

```
    public class App {


     public void setLogger(Logger logger){
         this.logger = logger;


     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In app.xml

```
<bean id="log" class="org.apache.log4j.Logger" factory-method="getRootLogger"/>

<bean id="app" class="com.comptel.mc.App" >
    <property name="logger" ref="log"/>
</bean>
```

Then you can get the initialized bean in your code

```
App bean = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app.xml").getBean(App.class);
```

Comment: Glad that it helped. Could you mark the question as answered and +1 it. Thanks!

Comment: I am really so sorry , Vote Up requires 15 reputation, and I dont have, but you are really so nice, thank u again